# Error converting varchar to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I want to convert from `CRSE_EDTE` (string) to `datetime`. Current `CRSE_EDTE` date format is `YYYYMM`, so I decided to put 28 as day for every date (DD).

```
select 
    try_convert(datetime, [CRSE_EDTE], 112) + CRSE_EDTE + '28' as new_CRSE_EDTE
FROM 
   [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
```

I get an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your database to play with, but would something like this work?

```
select try_convert(datetime,LEFT([CRSE_EDTE], 4)+'-'+RIGHT([CRSE_EDTE],2)+'-28',111) as new_CRSE_EDTE
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I have try your code, error here Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1991-1 -' to data type int.

Comment: Can you help me on above problem. I was update another problrm

Comment: Do you want to post the updated part as a new question? There may be others who know the MSSQL update command better than I do. Just leave a link to the new question here in the comments, and a link to this question in your new question.
While you're doing that, I'll see if I can figure it out, but if I can't you'll have a greater chance of getting an answer with a new question.

Comment: Ok. already create new post. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986502/sql-error-transfer-one-field-to-another-database-and-table