# SQL Error transfer one field to another database and table

Tags: sql-server

I want to transfer from new_CRSE_EDTE to other database and table.

My code is here

```
select try_convert(datetime,LEFT([CRSE_EDTE], 4)+'-'+RIGHT([CRSE_EDTE],2)+'-28',111) as new_CRSE_EDTE
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
update DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
set new_TarikhTamatPengajian = new_CRSE_EDTE
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
where DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STUDENTN]
collate latin1_general_CI_AI
```

This code is working, but only for years that start with 2020.

Original data from CRSE_EDTE have various years, for example 1991-10-11 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, backup your database(s) before trying this code.  It is untested:

```
update DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
set new_TarikhTamatPengajian = (
select TOP 1 try_convert(datetime,LEFT([CRSE_EDTE], 4)+'-'+RIGHT([CRSE_EDTE],2)+'-28',111) as new_CRSE_EDTE
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
where DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STUDENTN]
collate latin1_general_CI_AI)
```

Comment: i already pun collate Latin1_General_CI_AS. But the problem is same Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 32
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I've never used the collate command, but it looks to me like that is how it is supposed to be used. As always, make sure your database is backed up.

Comment: I have try you code above. Now already 1 hour 30 minutes still not complete executing. It's normal?

Comment: How big is your database?

Comment: Woah! It may not be the most optimised query, but that is a long time!  Are you able to see your table to know whether it is updating correctly (ex.: in another tab/program)?

Comment: I'm not run another program. I also can view to updated table because of this process. Should I waiting or stop it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  If you haven't stopped it yet and it is still not finished, I think I'd stop it.  Then check and see if it has modified any of the records correctly.